# Vorgangspassiv oder Zustandspassiv

Tags: grammar-identification

When something occured in the past I cannot always decide whether to use the Vorgangspassiv or Zustandspassiv. Which of thethe following two sentences is correct and why?

> Notts County wurde in 1862 gegründet

or

> Notts County war in 1862 gegründet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> <s>Notts County wurde in 1862 gegründet</s>
>
> <s>Notts County war in 1862 gegründet</s>

These are both wrong, because it's *im Jahr* or *im Jahre* **or nothing**.

> Notts County wurde (im Jahr) 1862 gegründet.

This means the action of founding Notts County happened in 1862. It's a *Vorgang*, an action.

> Notts County war (im Jahr) 1862 gegründet.

This means, by the year 1862, Notts County had already been founded. It does not specify when it happened exactly but says it was there in 1862. That's a description of the *Zustand* in the year 1862.

*Zustandspassiv* is often accompanied by explaining adverbs/particles:

> Notts County war (im Jahr) 1862, als die Football Association noch nicht einmal existierte, **bereits** gegründet.

This *bereits* emphasizes the fact the act of founding was completed before that of the Football Association.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding your answer shouldn't that be "im Jahren"?

Comment: No. *Im Jahr**e*** is the old dative with *e*. Dative plural would be *in den Jahren*.

Comment: If you need a clear and structured answer - ask Janka.